# Getting crontab to change its working directory to execute a PHP script

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, php, cron

I have a PHP scheduler script I need apache to execute on a cron schedule. Testing this command from command line works fine:

```
$    ! test -e /var/www/html/maintenance.flag && cd /var/www/html/shell && /bin/php ./scheduler.php --action cron --mode default
```

When I test this script using the command shown below as my apache user or add it to the apache cron I get this error: **Could not open input file: ./scheduler.php**

```
$    sudo -H -u apache bash -c "! test -e /var/www/html/maintenance.flag && cd /var/www/html/shell &&  /bin/php ./scheduler.php --action cron --mode default"
```

Note that scheduler.php is a symlink with read/write/execute on the on the link and source file (`chmod ug+rwx scheduler.php ./vendor/vendor/package/src/scheduler.php`).

I originally tried simply running `php /var/www/html/shell/scheduler.php --action cron --mode default`, however the PHP script references files in the same directory which is why I need apache/cron to execute the file from within that directory.

**Edit**

Tried using a script file but am still seeing the same error.

Created a cron.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/shell

#For Testing - remember, this is a symlink file
ls -l 'scheduler.php'

#Run Scheduler
/bin/php ./scheduler.php --action cron --mode always
/bin/php ./scheduler.php --action cron --mode default
```

*Tested with:*

```
sudo -H -u apache bash -c "! test -e /var/www/html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /var/www/html/cron.sh"
```

*Output:*

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache webroot 53 Oct 26 10:36 scheduler.php -> ../vendor/aoepeople/aoe_scheduler/shell/scheduler.php
Could not open input file: scheduler.php
Could not open input file: scheduler.php
```

Comment: Use full paths for everything in the cron and you should be set. And use absolute paths inside your script if necessary.

Comment: `ls -lL 'scheduler.php'`. Does the user you're running as have `r-x` on the `scheduler.php` file and at least `r--` on each of the directories in `../vendor/aoepeople/aoe_scheduler/shell/` ?

Comment: Yes, the output of `$    ls -lL scheduler.php` is `-rwxrwxr-x 1 centos apache 17359 Oct 26 10:35 scheduler.php`

Comment: The same goes for the directory `./vendor/aoepeople/aoe_scheduler/shell`

Comment: Please add the output of `namei -lx /var/www/html/shell/scheduler.php`

Answer (score 6):

Each of the sub expressions to `&&` (`test...`,`cd ...` and `/bin/php...`) execute in different subshells, and cannot pass context (like `$PWD`) among themselves.

Rather than put your command in your `crontab`, wrap it in a simple `bash` script, and call that script from `crontab`. E.g.:
In `crontab`:

```
! test -e /var/www/html/maintenance.flag && /usr/local/bin/maint
```

and, in `/usr/local/bin/maint`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/shell
/bin/php ./scheduler.php --action cron --mode default"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @waltinator the statement about each subexpression to `&&` having its own subshell is not true. To verify, run a simple command like `cd ~/ && echo $PWD && cd /tmp && echo $PWD`